# Unable to compile any file but Main

Tags: dart

I'm starting to get into Dart but I'm having trouble with compiling it.

I have 2 files:
Main.dart
TurtleDart.dart

Main.dart houses my `void main()` and imports TurtleDart.dart. At this point, TurtleDart.dart only houses an empty class with a constructor.

When compiling Main.dart it all goes fine... I think (I'm getting a 400 line JS file), however when compiling TurtleDart.dart, I get the following error:

> TurtleDart.dart:
>   Error: Could not find 'main'.
>
> Error: Compilation failed.

I know why the error comes forth, but I don't want to implement void main() into this file, because I want to use this as a class file.

My logic is that I want to call Main.dart to initialize a new TurtleDart instance, which handles everything else.

How can I manage this?

I'm using PHPStorm 7.1.3 with the Dart plugin.

Comment: I dunno how exactly works the dart2js, so i wont answer completely, but you don't have to build each dart file one by one... 
building your entry point (here, Main.dart) should be enough...

Comment: @Vloz you are right, you shoud make it an answer.

Comment: @Vloz so basically, because my Main.dart imports TurtleDart.dart, it automatically compiles TurtleDart.dart aswell?

Comment: @Vloz I'll be damned it does too! Please submit your comment as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dart2js will compile all needed libraries and files automatically. Generating your "main"-file will create the javascript code with all required files. So no need to compile each file separately.

Comment: Voting up, but not accepting as answer. In all fairness, Vloz came with the answer first.

Comment: oh sorry, had the question open a little and answered too late probably :/

Comment: Accepting anyway, he doesn't seem to respond.